# How to allow direct access from browser to a `page` contained in a SPA on a chrome extension?

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome-extension, vuejs2, single-page-application, vue-router

I have been working on a chrome extension using vue 3, vue-router and vue-x.

The extension is a `Single Page Application`, so if I understand correctly, it means that all incoming traffic should go through a root page and then vue-router handles the rendering while giving the user the impression that he changed page when in reality, he did not.
According to this part of vue-router [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations), you normally need something server side to make sure your root page is always served (nginx, apache, etc).

I need to reproduce this behaviour for my chrome-extension, and I have tried playing with the `manifest.json` but without any success so far. When I try to access to my other page, I have a `File not found` error. If I was to create an `other-page.html`, it renders but it wouldn't be a `SPA` anymore. I could try to put some hacky JS inside this other page but I was wondering if there was any more elegant way to handle this.

**tl;dr**: How to allow direct access from browser to a `page` contained in a SPA on a chrome extension.

Comment: Extensions don't have a server indeed. Use the router in hash mode.

Comment: It works indeed with the hash-mode. I might just drop it and go with the hashed navigation. Thanks @wOxxOm

Comment: @wOxxOm, would you mind posting your answer with a few details so I can validate it?

Comment: It'd be more useful if you post an answer yourself with the relevant fragments of the actual code.